# Android MVVM BindingClass does not generate the full path of ViewModel

Tags: android, mvvm, android-databinding, android-viewmodel

In my implementation of MVVM pattern, I have encountered the following[image]

Above is my Activity class trying to bind with the viewModel in the layout file
[image]

Above is the related XML

Note : The path of the viewModel is same from .CoreModules. Declaring viewModel variable in XML required full path, while the generated Binding file has the path starting from CoreModules only.

Giving an error : Type Mismatch

My generated binding class with incomplete path looks like below :

[image]

Comment: just fix import class at activity

Comment: @StanislavBondar, I didn't get that? Following are my imports : import android.os.Bundle
import driver.flyer.com.flyerdriver.CoreModules.Application.BaseActivity
import android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModelProviders
import android.databinding.DataBindingUtil
import driver.flyer.com.flyerdriver.CoreModules.SplashScreen.MVVM.SplashScreenViewModel
import driver.flyer.com.flyerdriver.R
import driver.flyer.com.flyerdriver.databinding.SplashScreenBinding

Comment: The binding class that is being generated is importing half path of the view model

Comment: @StanislavBondar, Any insight with you regarding the issue? My every Binding class is have imports problem giving me compile time errors

Comment: is `CoreModules` a class or package name?

Comment: @StanislavBondar, Its a package

Comment: Binding is case sensitive. use only lowercase for package names

Comment: @StanislavBondar , It worked. Thanks